# .htaccess rewrite subdomain to subdirectory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a tricky one and did not find a solution yet after more time spent on this than i'd like to admint.

Is it possible to use .htaccess to show the content of a subdomain in a subdirectory?

Example:

```
http://sub.example.com/
http://sub1.example.com/
http://sub2.example.com/
```

should be displayed as

```
http://example.com/sub/
http://example.com/sub1/
http://example.com/sub2/
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. This one should work:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www)\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/%1 [R=301,L]
```